# Overlapping sound i javascript

Tags: javascript

How to create overlapping sound in javascript, so one sound will play even when the other one is still playing?
I have that code:

```
var audio = new Audio("boom.wav");
```

and when something happens:

```
audio.play();
```

What must I do to do that?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. What do you mean by overlapping? Can you [edit] your question and clarify what you’re trying to do?

Comment: What isn’t working? What is the problem? Where are you trying to play the second sound? You have only posted the code to play one sound.

Comment: @Xufox I did it. I hope that will clarify everything.

Comment: @Xufox I am making game. Sound plays when collision occurs. And there is posibililty that one explosion will occur after another, but in that case only one sound plays...

Comment: How many `Audio` objects do you create and how exactly do you create them?

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a game, I would definitely recommend using a sound library.
For example: [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/soundjs). Of course many game development libraries come with sound management too.

A simple pure JS solution, could be to initialise the sound as many times as it may overlap, then check if the sound is currently playing N times and play the next sound initialised.

Example:

```
GAMEOBJECT._audio = [
    new Audio('assets/snd/slide.wav'),
    new Audio('assets/snd/slide.wav'),
    new Audio('assets/snd/drink.wav'),
    new Audio('assets/snd/drink.wav')
];
GAMEOBJECT._audio[0].pair = GAMEOBJECT._audio[1];
GAMEOBJECT._audio[2].pair = GAMEOBJECT._audio[3];

Audio.prototype.isPlaying = function () {return !this.paused;};
Audio.prototype.playSound = function () {
    if (this.isPlaying()) {
        this.pair.play();
    }
    this.play();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To let sounds overlap you should create different Audio objects.
Instead of

```
var audio = new Audio("boom.wav");
audio.play();
//...
audio.play();
```

you should

```
var audio1 = new Audio("boom.wav");
audio1.play();
//...
var audio2 = new Audio("boom.wav");
audio2.play();
```